# Suggestion for a more efficient way to remove duplicate through a column left to right instead of using if statement

Tags: vba, excel

I have this table:

```
Year    apple    apple     apple     apple    apple    apple     orange    orange     orange    orange    grape     grape    grape    durian    durian
1987
1988
1989
1990
1991
1992
1993
```

I have not filled in the table yet, but now I'm looking to remove the duplicate in the headers first, so I can get the final output like this:

```
Year    apple    orange    grape   durian
1987
1988
1989
1990
1991
1992
1993
```

I'm currently using the if statement to do the removal, which is very inefficient.

```
Sub test()
Dim i As Integer

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
lastcol = 1 + Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column   'define last column

Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, lastcol)).Select

Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("C1:Z1"), Order1:=xlAscending, 
Orientation:=xlLeftToRight                       'sort the column alphabetically

For i = 2 To lastcol
If Cells(1, i).Value = Cells(1, i).Offset(0, 1).Value Then
Cells(1, i).Select
Selection.Delete shift:=xlToLeft
    If Cells(1, i).Value = Cells(1, i).Offset(0, 1).Value Then
    Cells(1, i).Select
    Selection.Delete shift:=xlToLeft
        If Cells(1, i).Value = Cells(1, i).Offset(0, 1).Value Then
        Cells(1, i).Select
        Selection.Delete shift:=xlToLeft
            If Cells(1, i).Value = Cells(1, i).Offset(0, 1).Value Then
            Cells(1, i).Select
            Selection.Delete shift:=xlToLeft
                If Cells(1, i).Value = Cells(1, i).Offset(0, 1).Value Then
                Cells(1, i).Select
                Selection.Delete shift:=xlToLeft
Else
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If

Next
End Sub
```

Anyone can come up with suggestion to kill all the apples and oranges?

Maybe can be efficient enough I can skip the sorting process too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

or you could use `SortedList` object

```
Sub ProcessRow()
    Dim cell As Range, list As Object, j As Long

    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range("B1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
            For Each cell In .Cells
                If Not list.contains(cell.Value2) Then list.Add cell.Value2, 1
            Next
            .ClearContents
            For j = 0 To list.Count - 1
                .Cells(1, j + 1).Value = list.getkey(j)
            Next
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
dim i as long

with worksheets("sheet1")
    for i=.cells(1, .columns.count).end(xltoleft).column to 2 step -1
        if application.match(.cells(1, i), .rows(1), 0) < i then
            .columns(i).entirecolumn.delete
        end if
    next i

    'optional lateral sorting of first row only
    With .Range(.Cells(1, "B"), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Cells(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, Header:=xlNo
    End With

    'optional lateral sorting of all rows according to first row as key
    With .Range(.Cells(1, "B"), .Cells(.cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Cells(1), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                    Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, Header:=xlNo
    End With

end with
```

Comment: If you require a lateral sort, that can easily be added.

Comment: Hi @Jeeped! It worked like a charm, but I guess I can't skip the alphabetical sorting eh? It works well under the assumption that the table is already sorted alphabetically

Answer (score 1):

The usual, use collections to remove duplicates.  I used an ArrayLists for it's sort method.

```
Sub ProcessRow()
    Dim cell As Range, Target As Range, list As Object
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set Target = .Range("B1", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    End With

    For Each cell In Target
        If Not list.contains(cell.Value) And cell.Value <> "" Then list.Add cell.Value
    Next

    list.Sort
    Target.ClearContents
    Target.Resize(1, list.Count).Value = list.ToArray
End Sub
```